# How can I prevent Firefox from loading images?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a rudimentary screen scraper tool as an FF add-on (using DOM and xpaths). Currently, it runs fine. However, it also runs very slowly, as Firefox takes some time to request and download all the non-textual elements on each page (simply writing a separate application that parses the raw HTML is not feasible as some of the pages that need scraping make rather complicated AJAX requests). While I have seen 'Image block' and 'Flash block' plugins, these all seem to merely prevent the images/flash from displaying, rather than actually suppressing the GET requests.

So my question is this: is there any way for me to prevent Firefox from issuing these GET requests to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences -> Content -> "Load images automatically".

Comment: Is there an equivalent for stopping requests for linked stylesheets, scripts, flash, etc?

Comment: The option appears to no longer be available (FFox 23, GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 0):

[Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozzila.org/firefox/addon/adblock-plus) (or Adblock) can block images and more...

after installing, on the upper menu (aside of address bar) there appears an icon, right click>Options> Edit Filter:

The filter to block:

 GIF images would be ***.gif***

 Flash would be **.swf**

 and etc..

if you need to enable for specific site, just click icon and Enable/Pause for this site. then reload page to see images and etc..

for only specific site, like this:  `http://ad.uk.doubleclick.net/*.swf`